# Applescript doesn't recognize full-screen windows (?)

Tags: applescript

I need a script that involves going through windows of a specific process, but for some reason it doesn't recognize windows that are in "fullscreen-mode", so for example, the following script works (given you have at least one Finder window):

```
tell application "System Events"
    set procList to a reference to (every process whose name is "Finder")
    repeat with proc in procList
        repeat with win in (windows of proc)
           say "I found at least one window"
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

But if you try to toggle "fullscreen" for that window, the script no longer recognizes it. Why is that?

Comment: Sorry, what does "the script no longer recognizes it" mean?

Comment: It doesn't see it. Like the window doesn't exist. But it's there. It just in "Fullscreen" mode

Comment: Yes, that's right, System Events does not see fullscreen windows as belonging to processes. You can ask the Finder for its windows instead.

Comment: Ah, well. I'm dealing with an app that actually doesn't have "Application Bundle" (Zathura), so `tell application "zathura"` won't work, but, going like that (through the process handle) works, except that I can't find a way to access fullscreen windows... sigh

Comment: Yeah, this is clearly an issue and I don't think you can solve it for non-applescript-enabled apps.